# Why isn't this merge fast-forwarded?

Tags: git

From the Git Book:

"if the current branch has not diverged from the other--so every commit present in the current branch is already contained in the other--then git just performs a "fast forward"

I'm trying to reproduce this scenario, but this doesn't produce any fast forwards:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /work/fun/git_experiments/.git/
$ echo initial > readme && git add readme && git commit -a -m Created
[master (root-commit) 74495b9] Created
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 readme
$ git branch b1
$ echo modified > readme && git commit -a -m "Modified"
[master d40d5fb] Modified
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
$ git checkout b1
Switched to branch 'b1'
$ echo modified > readme && git commit -a -m "Modified"
[    b1 46fd337] Modified
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
$ git merge master
Merge made by recursive.
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because although the content of the two commits are the same, they are not actually the same commit (N.B.: one is commit ID `d40d5fb` and the other is `46fd337`). Thus, branch `b1` contains a commit not in `master`, so not all of the commits in `b1` are a descendant of `master`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add my answer, where I merged back to master and got a fast forward this time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155462/why-isnt-this-merge-fast-forwarded/6155521#6155521

Answer (score 0):

The *contents* of the commits are identical, but the commits themselves are not. In this particular case, you’re merging `d40d5fb` into `46fd337`, so it needs to perform a proper merge tying those two commits with a single head. The only way for two people to independently write the exact same commits is if the name, email, and timestamp are identical as well.

Try rebasing instead, which will squash commits that introduce identical diffs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge b1
Updating d40d5fb..fd337c3
Fast-forward
$
```

When I merge back the changes to master, then it is fast forwarded because the same exact commit just happened on b1 ... while my example wasn't really the same commits.

Comment: Try running `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` after each commit or merge to get a picture of where your branches are.